# Magento 2 Add to Cart : Performance testing using Jmeter

Tags: magento2, performance

We are doing performance testing on Magento 2 platform.

How should we include following URL in jMeter script

```
cart/ad/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly9wcm9kLWFiYm90dC1zdG9yZS1leHRlcm5hbC1hbGIuYWJib3R0c3RvcmUuY29tLzE0LTFvemNhbi1jYXNlb2Y2LTU1MjUxLmh0bWw,/product/153/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should extract this URL from a product page.

For example, see [benchmark.jmx](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/setup/performance-toolkit/benchmark.jmx) used by Magento Performance Team to measure Magento performance

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add this in "Add to cart" request, then you don't need to add this. As you can simply add the products to the cart without adding the "uenc" to your request URL.